# Adding double quotes to two fields in unix

Tags: linux, unix, sed, awk

i have a file with 3 columns, the 2nd column is lat/long and may or may not have data.

```
2012-01-10 21:27:52.811,,ABC   -- No lat/long
2012-01-10 21:27:52.811,37.8889329,-112.1876328,XYZ  -- with lat long
```

Can some one help me with a sed/awk/perl  to transform it to

```
2012-01-10 21:27:52.811,"37.8889329,-112.1876328",XYZ
```

In all other cases it should not add any double quotes

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why does it have to be a one-liner? With which part are you struggling? Also *how many* columns? What's the delimiter?

Comment: Edited the question, one liner would be better, but i will be happy with any answer to start with.. thanks..

Comment: I've never understood why people think one-liners are better. They've obviously never had to maintain other people's one-liners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably do something like this, using `awk`:

```
% echo '2012-01-10 21:27:52.811,,ABC   -- No lat/long
2012-01-10 21:27:52.811,37.8889329,-112.1876328,XYZ  -- with lat long
' | awk -F',' -v OFS=','  '
$2 && $3 {
    $2 = "\"" $2
    $3 = $3 "\""
}

1
'
2012-01-10 21:27:52.811,,ABC   -- No lat/long
2012-01-10 21:27:52.811,"37.8889329,-112.1876328",XYZ  -- with lat long
```

This assumes that the fields are comma-delimited on the way in and the way out.

If the second and third fields are populated then

- Put a `"` before the second field
- Put a `"` after the third field

Print all lines (`1`).

There are a lot of assumptions here, so you'll have to dig out the [sed & awk book](http://tinyurl.com/SedAwkBook) and tweak this to meet your needs.

Comment: @learner and this would be the one-liner of this fine solution - `awk '$2{$2="\""$2;$3=$3"\""}1' FS=OFS=',' filename` … +1 to the solution

Comment: @Jaypal: I deliberately didn't put this all on one line. Thanks for demonstrating why!

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/^[^,]*,,/!s/,\([^,]*,[^,]*\)/,"\1"/' file
2012-01-10 21:27:52.811,,ABC   -- No lat/long
2012-01-10 21:27:52.811,"37.8889329,-112.1876328",XYZ  -- with lat long
```

Answer (score 0):

Just with bash:

```
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=,

while read a b c d; do
    if [[ -z "$d" ]]; then
        printf "%s,,%s\n" "$a" "$c"
    else
        printf "%s,\"%s,%s\",%s\n" "$a" "$b" "$c" "$d"
    fi
done < filename > filename.new

IFS=$oldIFS
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the constraints, you can use sed and specify the fields to change:

```
sed '/,,/! s/,/,"/1; s/,/",/3'
```

This works by restricting the substitutions only to those lines where two commas `,,` do not occur together. Within the lines where substitutions will be made, we use numeric flags to add a double-quote after the first comma and before the third comma.